# Spring test : strange behavior of context config caching between test classes ?

Tags: spring, integration-testing, spring-integration, spring-test

I am writing tests for a Spring Integration project, and I am running into something strange : I've read about how Spring caches the context between tests and how we can force to clean the cache with @DirtiesContext annotation. However, I'm not able to explain the behavior I observe, and it makes me think it's maybe a bug...

I have 2 different tests :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:myInterface-core.xml",
                                    "classpath:myInterface-datasource-test.xml"})
public class PropertyConfigurerTest {


   @Test
   public void shouldResolvePropertyForOutPutFile(){

   }
}
```

(it does nothing, simply loads the context, intentionnaly)

And another one, more complex with actual tests in it (skipping them in below snippet) :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
 "classpath:myInterface-core.xml",
 "classpath:myInterface-rmi.xml",
 "classpath:myInterface-datasource-test.xml"})
public class MontranMessagesFlowTest {
...
}
```

As you can see, these 2 tests don't load exactly the same config : second test loads one extra config file that is not required for first one.

When I run these 2 tests one after the other, second test is failing : in a nutshell, the goal of the test is to insert 2 rows in inMemory DB, start my Spring Integration flow and assert with a listener (inside a jms:listener-container) that I've received 2 JMS messages on the outbound side. I see in debug mode that actually the **2 messages don't go to same listener** so I get one message instead of the 2 I expect. Somehow, the fact that I'm loading some elements of the context in first test (even if I don't do anything with them) has an impact on the second test.

I have found 2 different workarounds :

- adding `@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)` on my first test.
- modify the list of Spring files that I load in my first test, so that it matches exactly the one defined in the second test.

But still, I don't understand the rationale, and it looks like a bug to me.

I am using Spring Test 4.1.4.RELEASE. I've put the minimum code necessary in a separate project to be able to reproduce. I can share it if required.

Does anybody have an explanation for this ? Bug or not ?

Thanks

Vincent

Comment: No it isn't. You have a single database, 2 instances of things that listen... So you basically have competing consumers with this setup...

Comment: why do you say I have "2 instances of things that listen" ? tests are not run in parallel, but one after the other. When first test ends, Spring Integration flow is shut down. But when it starts again in second test, I have a "ghost" listener from 1st test.

Comment: Because the context is cached... It is still alive and so are the beans in it (assuming you are running both tests in a single run after each other).

Comment: See my answer we have started adding `@DirtiesContext` to all the SI tests to ensure active components are stopped.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still missing something : I understand it's cached, but in that case, why does it create another instance of it during the second test ? and why does setting the exact same config makes it work ?

Comment: It's a different context for the second case so the cached one can't be used.

Comment: OK, thanks both Gary and M. Deinum for your inputs. I think I understand a bit better what is going on. I guess what is misleading is the annotation DirtiesContext itself : a dirtied context is only one reason for reloading the whole context. In my case, context is clean, , but still I need to remove it from cache to avoid side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@M. Deinum is correct in his comment.

For what it's worth, in Spring Integration framework tests themselves, we have started adding `@DirtiesContext` to all tests, to ensure any active components (such as inbound message-driven adapters) are always stopped after the tests complete.

This also has a performance/memory usage improvement for large test suites.

Comment: Why is it an improvement in performance/memory usage for large test suites ? Isn't it the opposite, since by using @DirtiesContext, you prevent caching and force all test classes to reload everything ?

Comment: It only makes sense to cache a context if you are using the __SAME__ context in multiple tests. In your case you are using different contexts, and the "other" one is left running in the background.